# MPI4py: MPI Communicate through a loop between processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi4py

I have 2 processes in my program. Where `process(0)` is the master and `process(1)` is slave. There is a common loop for both (which increments from 0 to 4). 
I am trying to send a value(`i`) to `process(1)` from `process(0)`. But `process(1)` does not get the new values of `i` from `process(0)`.

```
cw = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = cw.Get_rank()
nProcesses = cw.Get_size()

currentTrial = np.zeros(nProcesses-1, dtype='int32')
receivedTrial = np.zeros(1, dtype='int32')

i = 0   
while (i < 5):
    if (rank == 0):
        currentTrial[0] = 0
        #print(i)
        sendToSlave = cw.Isend(currentTrial[0:1], dest=1)
        print(sendToSlave.Test())

        i = i+ 1
        currentTrial[0] = i

    if (rank != 0):
        #receive a trial number 
        receiveFromMaster = cw.Recv(receivedTrial[:], source=0)
        print("rank", rank,receivedTrial)
```

This is currently the output I get:

```
True
rank 1 [0]
True
True
True
True
rank 1 [0]
rank 1 [0]
rank 1 [0]
rank 1 [0]
```

Ideally, `process(1)` should print `[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]`

Comment: Try replacing `receivedTrial[:]` with `receivedTrial` in the receive call.